# Is there a way to keep the notification open? Prevent autohide?

Tags: macos, notifications

Is there a way to keep the notification bar from auto hiding?  I'd basically like to keep it open/expanded on the right side of my screen.

Comment: would love to know a way to get this to work. I have a few widgets with Yosemite that'd be helpful to be always displayed like World Clock when planning meetings across timezones.